# Empty attachment on mails send through zend mail

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using Zend framework 1.12.
Basically, I am trying to send attachments (images, pdf) from one of my site using Zend mail. The mail is sent and I received it in a perfect way. But the problem there is that the attachments are empty.
This is my code.

```
$mail=new Zend_Mail();
$file= file path;
$content = file_get_contents($file); 
$attachment = new Zend_Mime_Part($content);
$attachment->type = 'application/octet-stream';
$attachment->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
$attachment->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
$attachment->filename = abc.jpg; 
$mail->addAttachment($attachment); 
$mail->setBodyText($message);
$mail->setFrom($email);
$mail->setSubject($subject);
$mail->addTo($to);      //email address
$mail->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

More details are available about zend_mail with attachment in given link, hope it helps you.
https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.mail.attachments.html

Comment: i am referring it regularly but i am unable to solve my problem from here.
anyway thanks Prabin bro.

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be with `application/octet-stream` mime type. That type is not viewable in most email apps.
 Use,

```
$attachment->type=mime_content_type($file);
```

It might work.

Comment: i have tried using that but still the problem is same.